# Qt. как выводить в консоль, а не в "панель вывода"?

Tags: c++, qt, консоль

Windows. Qt 4.2.0

вывод приложения происходит в "панель вывода". а нужно в консоль.

файл .pro

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = test
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Проект -> Запуск -> Запускать в терминале

[image]

Comment: ты лучший, большое спасибо